# How to rollback child transaction if any exception in parent transaction?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, distributed-transactions, two-phase-commit

I have two transaction manager for two database. I need to persist same data into both databases. If one transaction failed, other one need rollback. I have done like below

```
public interface DataService {
    void saveData();
}

@Service
public class DataServiceImpl implements DataService {

    @Autowired
    private DataRepository dataRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private OrDataRepository orDataRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("orService")
    private OrService orDataServiceImpl;
    
    
    @Override
    @Transactional(transactionManager = "transactionManager", rollbackFor = {RuntimeException.class})
    public void saveData() {
        Data data = new Data();
        data.setCompKey(UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(1,5));
        data.setName("data");
        dataRepository.save(data);
        orDataServiceImpl.save();
        //throw new RuntimeException("");
    }
}

public interface OrService {
    void save();
}


@Service("orService")
public class OrDataServiceImpl implements OrService {
    @Autowired
    private OrDataRepository orDataRepository;
    
    
    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = {RuntimeException.class})
    public void save() {
        OrData data = new OrData();
        data.setCompKey(UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(1,5));
        data.setName("ordata");
        orDataRepository.save(data);
    }
}
```

I have two transaction manager (entityManager & orEntityManager) for two different DB.

If any exception in OrDataServiceImpl save method, data is not getting persisted in both DB. But if any exception in DataServiceImpl saveData method, data is getting persisted into  OrData table.

I want to rollback the data from both DB if any exception.

chainedTransactionManager is deprecated. So can't use. atomikos and bitronix also can't use due to some restrictions. Kindly suggest better way to achieve distributed transation

Answer (score 0):

- The code need to be refactored, edit the DataServiceImpl.save() method.

  Comment the orDataServiceImpl.save() line

  ```
   public void saveData() {
   Data data = new Data();
   data.setCompKey(UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(1,5));
   data.setName("data");
   dataRepository.save(data);
   //orDataServiceImpl.save();
   //throw new RuntimeException("");
   }
  ```
- Refactor/Edit the OrDataService Interface

  ```
   public interface OrDataService {

   void save(String uuid); 
   void delete(String uuid); 
  //will be use for compensating transaction
  ```

  }
- Update the OrDataServiceImpl class to implement above interface
- Write new orchestration Method and use compensating transaction to rollback

  pseudo code

  1. `call OrDataServiceImpl.save()`
  2. if step#1 was success
  3. ```
       -> DataServiceImpl.saveData()
     ```
  4. ```
      if Exception at step#3,
     ```
  5. ```
           ->OrDataServiceImpl.delete() [//to rollback]
     ```
  6. 
  7. else if, Exception at step#1
     //do nothing

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For simple insert it's easy to follow above mentioned flow. For delete, complex update we can't use it. I feel that this is not a rollback. We are programmatically deleting the data

Comment: This is as per with Saga Orchestrator Pattern, of course you can explore - Saga  Choreography pattern. And more complex 2 PC commit - which most of the time doesn't work as expected..

Comment: Agree. I went through compensating transaction, saga design pattern. For larger application we can't write a logic to undo for each transaction. If we follow saga design pattern it will need huge effort.

Comment: I am thinking once first transaction got success i can call the second transaction method. If first transaction failed, i am not going to call second transaction method. Is there any way to rollback the first transaction if second transaction failed